# Flutter - Unable to Install Application to Emulator

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project that previously run on Flutter 2.2. Recently, I upgraded to Flutter 2.10 but unable to run the application on Android emulator. I've followed the instruction on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects. I run the emulator on Ubuntu.

What I've tried (from other StackOverflow posts) didn't work at all:

- Restarting emulator
- Removing dependencies (I removed all dependencies in pubspec.yaml)
- Accepting Android SDK licenses
- Using Android Pie version emulator
- Running `flutter clean`
- Uninstall the app on the emulator

`flutter doctor` shows no problem.
Sometimes the `run` process stuck on Installing/built APK, sometimes I get 'Error connecting to the service protocol'. I also get the following error

```
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(10386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10386): Process: com.app.example, PID: 10386
E/AndroidRuntime(10386): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.app.example-pnJtFUSDIe4xWUHIPO1jNQ==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.onAttachedToWindow(FlutterView.java:483)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18347)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(10386):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I can run the same code (on the same project) to web browser. I can run the same code on the emulator if it's copied to another newly created project which is created with Flutter 2.10. I also have copied `AndroidManifest.xml`, `build.gradle` from the new project to the old one, but also not working.

Any solution or suggestion what should I do to fix it.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Do share, cuz I'm facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you still have references to previous versions of android libraries com.android... , latest flutter uses androidX.

Make sure you don't have any of

```
implementation 'com.android....`
```

in your gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is late, but I hope it helps.

Since you're able to run the project on web browser and not Android emulator, the root of the problem seems to be in the Android section. And you've also added that you copied the **AndroidManifest.xml** and **build.gradle** file to the new project, which concludes that your problem lies in either the **AndroidManifest.xml** file or the **build.gradle** file.

I myself had the same problem and solved it by removing the following line from the **build.gradle/android** file:

```
subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If that's not your case then I would suggest adding lines *one by one* from the project into a newly created project and run if after adding each new line to find out what line is causing your app to crash.